# Delete single item in Firebase with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am struggling a bit understanding how to remove a single item from an object in Firebase with AngularJS.

This is my Firebase (only the interesting bit):

```
projects
 |
 `--- $id
 |     `-- Name
 |     `-- CreatorID
 |
user_project
 |
 `--- CreatorID
       `-- projectid
```

Every time a user creates an entry the same is added to the entries with a Creator ID equal to the user ID that I get from Firebase Simple Login. At the same time, my code creates a new item inside user_entries/CreatorID (so that I have a list of entries associated with every user).

Example:

```
projects
 |
 `--- JlagYdBNX1gyMVCoXBF
 |     `-- Name: "Activity 1"
 |     `-- CreatorID: "simplelogin:29"
 |
user_projects
 |
 `--- simplelogin:29
       `--JleI106xJgZf6_mGHUI: "JlagYdBNX1gyMVCoXBF"
```

Now my problem is that I can delete an entry, but I don't know how to track back and delete the same from user_entries (so that I am getting many orphans there).

I am using a factory:

```
app.factory('Project', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
  var projects = $firebase(ref.child('projects')).$asArray();

  var Project = {
    all: projects,
    create: function (project) {
      return projects.$add(project).then(function(projectRef) {
        $firebase(ref.child('user_projects').child(project.creatorUID))
        .$push(projectRef.name());
        return projectRef;
      });
    },
    delete: function (project) {
      var userid = project.creatorUID;
      return projects.$remove(project).then(function(projectRef) {
        //$firebase(ref.child('user_projects').child(userid))
        console.log(project.$id);
      });
    },
  };

  return Project;

});
```

I know that $remove has a callback returning the $id of the processed item so I tried to change *delete* to:

```
delete: function (project) {
  var userid = project.creatorUID;
  return projects.$remove(project).then(function(projectRef) {
    $firebase(ref.child('user_projects').child(userid))
    .$remove(projectRef.$id);
  });
},
```

but I get

*Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"*

Any hint on how to approach this problem?

Comment: I'm assuming you already tried `.$remove(project.$id)`? Apparently [from the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-removerecordorindex) the object passed to the call back is a regular Firebase object, *not* an Angular firebase object. I don't know why they decided to do it that way.

Comment: And of course, following the docs, you should be able to use `.$remove(projectRef.key())`.

Comment: Yes I tried with `project.$id`, no luck. But I guess it's because `project.$id` is the value, not the key in user_projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be not the cleanest solution but I found a way to achieve what I needed saving the unique ID of the user_projects entry id into the project itself:

```
 create: function (project) {
      return projects.$add(project).then(function(projectRef) {
        var projectId = projectRef.name();
        $firebase(ref.child('user_projects').child(project.creatorUID))
        .$push(projectId).then(function(userProjectRef) {
          var userProjectId = userProjectRef.name();
          $firebase(ref.child('projects').child(projectId).child('LinkID')).$set(userProjectId);
        });
        return projectRef;
      });
    },
```

So that in my firebase I get:

```
projects
 |
 `--- JlagYdBNX1gyMVCoXBF
 |     `-- Name: "Activity 1"
 |     `-- CreatorID: "simplelogin:29"
 |     `-- LinkID: "JleI106xJgZf6_mGHUI"
 |
user_projects
 |
 `--- simplelogin:29
       `--JleI106xJgZf6_mGHUI: "JlagYdBNX1gyMVCoXBF"
```

And then it's much easier to delete the entry:

```
delete: function (project) {
  var userId = project.creatorUID;
  var userProjectId = project.LinkID;
  return projects.$remove(project).then(function(projectRef) {
 $firebase(ref.child('user_projects').child(userId)).$remove(userProjectId);
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The [AngularFire documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-removerecordorindex) indicates that the object passed to the promise callback is a regular [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/) object, not an AngularFire reference. This means that you need to use `.key()` rather than `.$id`:

```
delete: function (project) {
  var userid = project.creatorUID;
  return projects.$remove(project).then(function(projectRef) {
    $firebase(ref.child('user_projects').child(userid))
    .$remove(projectRef.ref());
  });
},
```

Comment: Oh, I understand now... I tried that before and I got this: `Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "https://my_firebase.firebaseio.com/projects/-Jm24tOoN23k5PFhoNGB". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`